# Style Text Color and Hint Color For AutocompleteSupportFragment In Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, hint, autocompletesupportfragment

I cannot change the color of the hint text as well as the text when i select a place from Google Places.

Please see attached image.

I tried android:textColorHint and android:editTextColor to no avail. Thoughts?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide an option to specify color through attributes or styles. However, you can use these tweaks:

For Activity (after setContentView):

```
val searchView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input)

searchView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE)
searchView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

For Fragment (inside onViewCreated):

```
val searchView = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input)

searchView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE)
searchView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

> Warning: these are internal layout id's, which may be changed in the
> future. The information is valid for version 2.5.0